# Encountering errors while executing an insert operation in Hive(3.1.3) (RPC channel is closed.)

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hive, jar, rpc

### environment:

- hadoop 3.2.0
- spark  3.2.0
- hive   3.1.3
- 1 master, 2 workers
- hiveserver2 and master are in the same container

### Issue Description:

Encountering errors while executing an insert operation in Hive:

Error Messages:

```
Failed to monitor Job[-1] with exception 'java.lang.IllegalStateException(Connection to remote Spark driver was lost)' Last known state = SENT
Failed to execute spark task, with exception 'java.lang.IllegalStateException(RPC channel is closed.)'
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.spark.SparkTask. RPC channel is closed.
```

### Relevant Information in hive.log:

```
WARN [RPC-Handler-6] rpc.RpcDispatcher: Received error message:java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hive/spark/client/Job
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:756)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:473)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:405)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.util.DefaultClassResolver.readName(DefaultClassResolver.java:154)
    at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.util.DefaultClassResolver.readClass(DefaultClassResolver.java:133)
    at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readClass(Kryo.java:670)
    at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.read(ObjectField.java:118)
    at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.read(FieldSerializer.java:551)
    at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readClassAndObject(Kryo.java:790)
    at org.apache.hive.spark.client.rpc.KryoMessageCodec.decode(KryoMessageCodec.java:97)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageCodec$1.decode(ByteToMessageCodec.java:42)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:507)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:446)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:276)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageCodec.channelRead(ByteToMessageCodec.java:103)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:719)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:655)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:581)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:986)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hive.spark.client.Job
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:387)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    ... 42 more
.
2023-12-12T09:39:36,140  WARN [RPC-Handler-6] client.SparkClientImpl: Client RPC channel closed unexpectedly.
2023-12-12T09:39:36,140  WARN [RPC-Handler-6] rpc.RpcDispatcher: [ClientProtocol] Closing RPC channel with 1 outstanding RPCs.
2023-12-12T09:39:36,140  WARN [HiveServer2-Background-Pool: Thread-97] impl.RemoteSparkJobStatus: Failed to get APP ID.
java.util.concurrent.CancellationException: null
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.cancel(...)(Unknown Source) ~[netty-all-4.1.17.Final.jar:4.1.17.Final]
2023-12-12T09:39:36,162 ERROR [HiveServer2-Background-Pool: Thread-97] status.SparkJobMonitor: Failed to monitor Job[-1] with exception 'java.lang.IllegalStateException(Connection to remote Spark driver was lost)' Last known state = SENT
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Connection to remote Spark driver was lost
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:174)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.spark.status.RemoteSparkJobMonitor.startMonitor(RemoteSparkJobMonitor.java:70)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.spark.status.impl.RemoteSparkJobRef.monitorJob(RemoteSparkJobRef.java:60)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.spark.SparkTask.execute(SparkTask.java:146)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task.executeTask(Task.java:205)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TaskRunner.runSequential(TaskRunner.java:97)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.launchTask(Driver.java:2664)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.execute(Driver.java:2335)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.runInternal(Driver.java:2011)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1709)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1703)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.reexec.ReExecDriver.run(ReExecDriver.java:157)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation.runQuery(SQLOperation.java:224)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation.access$700(SQLOperation.java:87)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation$BackgroundWork$1.run(SQLOperation.java:316)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1730)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation$BackgroundWork.run(SQLOperation.java:329)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

2023-12-12T09:39:36,162 ERROR [HiveServer2-Background-Pool: Thread-97] spark.SparkTask: Failed to execute spark task, with exception 'java.lang.IllegalStateException(RPC channel is closed.)'
java.lang.IllegalStateException: RPC channel is closed.
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:174)
    at org.apache.hive.spark.client.rpc.Rpc.call(Rpc.java:275)
    at org.apache.hive.spark.client.SparkClientImpl$ClientProtocol.run(SparkClientImpl.java:565)
    at org.apache.hive.spark.client.SparkClientImpl.run(SparkClientImpl.java:155)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.spark.status.impl.RemoteSparkJobStatus.getAppID(RemoteSparkJobStatus.java:71)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.spark.SparkTask.execute(SparkTask.java:181)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task.executeTask(Task.java:205)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TaskRunner.runSequential(TaskRunner.java:97)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.launchTask(Driver.java:2664)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.execute(Driver.java:2335)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.runInternal(Driver.java:2011)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1709)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1703)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.reexec.ReExecDriver.run(ReExecDriver.java:157)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation.runQuery(SQLOperation.java:224)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation.access$700(SQLOperation.java:87)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation$BackgroundWork$1.run(SQLOperation.java:316)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1730)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation$BackgroundWork.run(SQLOperation.java:329)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

### Additional Investigation:

Further investigation using `yarn logs -applicationId` reveals that there are no errors reported in the logs. Additionally, the application status is displayed as "SUCCEEDED."